# What is the maximum frequency of 1000BASE-T?

Tags: networking

What is the maximum frequency supported by `1000BASE-T`?

- `CAT6` - `250MHz`
- `CAT6A` - `500MHz`
- `CAT7` - `600MHz`
- `CAT7A` - `1000MHz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear.

1000BASE-T works fine over CAT5E cable, although CAT6 cable is recommended.   (CAT6 can support 10 Gigabit)   You do not need even 250MHz for a gigabit connection - although I postulate that a higher "GHZ" rating translates into less crosstalk at longer distances.

[CAT5E is rated at 100MHz officially, but often 350MHz as a marketing gimmick.](http://www.directron.com/cableguide.html)

Comment: So CAT6A Would not be any better, other than the crosstalk (theatrically)? I have a cluster with 1000BASE-T transcoding video.

Comment: In practice using CAT6 over CAT5E for short runs will not make any difference to performance on a gigabit network.  If you are not getting gigabit speeds you would want to look at other factors (like how well the jacks are terminated, how much load the switch is pushing, if the systems can handle 1 gigabit of traffic).